# Let user copy and paste text in Text Box but disable manual Editing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, textbox

I am trying to create TextBox so that user can not type anything but they should be able to paste information using clip board text.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What is your question, exactly?  Currently, it just looks like you're telling us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for vague question. So I am trying to create TextBox that can only be editable by means of copy and paste.  

The user should not be able to manually type anything into the textbox, but only allow pasting into that textbox.
So far i have made CustomTextBox that extends TextBox class. 
And Override the following method.
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but why would you want to? All you're doing is making it harder to use the application. There is nothing here to stop someone from popping open notepad.exe, typing whatever they want, copying the text they just typed, and pasting it into your textbox thus bypassing your "no manual editing" requirement.

Comment: Hello! I just edited my answer because I had forgot to make the `InputIsCommand` variable reset to `False` when you _don't_ press CTRL + C or CTRL + V. Not doing so causes the user to be able to input text normally once you've pressed either of the combinations, so please see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the TextBox's [**`KeyPress` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) in which you always set the [**`e.Handled`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to True, unless when you are pressing a clipboard combination (CTRL + C, V).

To identify the clipboard combination you will also have to subscribe to the [**`KeyDown` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) in which you will be able to identify which key or key combination has been pressed, then via a `Boolean` variable (which you read from the `KeyPress` event) you can indicate whether to allow the combination or not.

Doing what I just described will cause any keyboard input (that is, not CTRL + C or CTRL + V) to *not* be handled by the TextBox, thus it won't add any characters unless you paste.

```vb
Dim InputIsCommand As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    InputIsCommand = e.Control = True AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.V OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.C)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not InputIsCommand
End Sub
```

C# version:

```cs
public Form1() //Form constructor.
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.KeyPress += textBox1_KeyPress;
    textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;
}

bool InputIsCommand = false;

private void textBox1_KeyDown(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    InputIsCommand = e.Control == true && (e.KeyCode == Keys.V || e.KeyCode == Keys.C);
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !InputIsCommand;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you still edit the text by highlighting a portion and using a mouse to select "cut"?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It is working now. But right now it only works with right click 'paste'. Is it possible with ctrl+v?

Comment: @bitnine : Yes, but he didn't ask not to be able to do so. Only not to type in it.

Comment: @Sagar0921 : Yes, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you very much. This is exactly what i wanted. One last thing, is it possible to enable ctrl+C to copy the text inside the textbox.  Currently, you can to right-click it to copy.  The ctrl+V works amazing!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sagar0921 : Sorry for the late reply, my phone died (yes I wrote the answer from my phone :) ). I have now fixed the CTRL + C combination too. -- I'm glad it worked!